# JavaScript performance issue, appending li into ul offline

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a performance related issue : it takes 10sec to load my ul -it contains more than 1000 li-.
Can you point me where the problem is. What can I optimize ?

Moreover I have some much trouble to read the profile result.

NB:  the DOM element template is offline until I send it to the sandbox

```
var displayAllHypotheses = function () {
    console.time('displayAllHypotheses');
    console.profile('displayAllHypotheses');

    var $template = $(_template);
    var $item_example = $template.find('#item-example').clone();
    var $list = $template.find('.content-ask ul.select-hypothese');

    $item_example.removeAttr('id');
    $template.find('#item-example').remove();

    _$template_item_selected = $template.find('.item-example').removeClass('item-example').clone();
    for (var i in _data_game.Hypotheses) {

        var $clone = $item_example.clone();
        var $a_select_hypothese = $clone.find('a');
        $a_select_hypothese.html(_data_game.Hypotheses[i].nom).data('hypotheseid', _data_game.Hypotheses[i].id);
        $a_select_hypothese.attr('href', '#' + i);
        if (!!_hypotheses_selected[_data_game.Hypotheses[i].id]) {
            $a_select_hypothese.addClass('inDaList');
        }
        $clone.appendTo($list);
    }

    $list.find('a').click(function () {

        $('#mod_hypothese .part-select .select-hypothese a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        displayChooseButton();

    });
    $item_example = null;
    $a_select_hypothese = null;
    $clone = null;
    $list = null;
    console.timeEnd('displayAllHypotheses');
    console.profileEnd('displayAllHypotheses');
    return $template;
};
var initTemplate = function (data) {
    console.time('initTemplate hypothese');
    console.profile('initTemplate hypothese');

    _template = data;
    var $template = displayAllHypotheses();

    $template.find('.close-modal').click(function () {
        _sandbox.notify('close hypothese', null);
    });
    _sandbox.setTemplate($template);
    initSearchBox();
    displaySelectedHypotheses();
    $template = null;

    console.timeEnd('initTemplate hypothese');
    console.profileEnd('initTemplate hypothese');
};
```

**EDIT**
So I tried the string concatenation :

```
 var displayAllHypothesesString = function () {
    console.time('displayAllHypothesesString');
    console.profile('displayAllHypothesesString');
    var $template = $(_template);
    var $list = $template.find('.content-ask ul.select-hypothese');
    var lis = '';
    _$template_item_selected = $template.find('.item-example').removeClass('item-example').clone();
    for (var i in _data_game.Hypotheses) {

        if (!_hypotheses_selected[_data_game.Hypotheses[i].id]) {
            lis += '<li><a data-hypotheseid="' + _data_game.Hypotheses[i].id + '" href="#' + i + '">' + _data_game.Hypotheses[i].nom + '</a></li>';
        } else {
            lis += '<li><a class="inDaList" data-hypotheseid="' + _data_game.Hypotheses[i].id + '" href="#' + i + '">' + _data_game.Hypotheses[i].nom + '</a></li>';

        }
    }
    $list.empty().append(lis);
    $list.find('a').click(function () {

        $('#mod_hypothese .part-select .select-hypothese a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        displayChooseButton();

    });

    console.timeEnd('displayAllHypothesesString');
    console.profileEnd('displayAllHypothesesString');
    return $template;
};
```

It's working fast enough !!
But now I have HTML snippet in my JS and if the web designer need to pimp the li he'll have to go to the JS file.

But I guess there is no workaround on this issue, is there ?

Comment: What's `_template`? A string or a DOM element?

Comment: _template is a string, $template is a jquery DOM element

Comment: Appending an HTML snippet as a string is faster than creating, manipulating, and appending a detached DOM tree - but the easiest bottleneck here is to not append all 1000 (that's a lot) at the same time. Can you modify the UX to maybe show more when you reach the bottom of the list and perhaps only append 10 or 20 at a time?

Comment: Well you have 10K items and you loop over them many times and manipulate them. It is going to be slow.

Comment: @Adam I'll give it a try with the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a variable and store all the data in it. Once you completed the loop, append it to the element you want so you dont have to call append that many times.

```
var listData;
for(var i; i<data.length; i++)
    listData += "<li>some data</li>"

$("#element").html(listData)
```

Something like that.

Comment: You should initialize `listData` to a string - otherwise the resultant operation from `listData += '<li>some data</li>'` will result in `undefined<li>some data</li>';`

Comment: String concatenation is actually worse, I did some test here http://jsfiddle.net/f01s10Lt/

Comment: @Su4p - Invalid test - you're still updating the `innerHTML` inside every loop iteration, you should concatenate your string and only update `innerHTML` once, after the loop is completed.

Comment: Your test append the ul every iteration. You should append it only once, after all iteration is completed. As redrawing the DOM is expensive

Comment: I'm not a big fan of having HTML snippet in my JS files... but I have to admit it's faster.